# How to open a mounted volume's location in OSX?

Tags: macos, terminal, finder

I'm writing a shell (bash) script which uses SSHFS (not that it should matter) to mount a network drive ND at a specific path P. Then, I want Finder to open a window/tab at path P/ND.

The problem is whenever I attempt to open the network drive, Finder opens a window not at path P/ND, but at *MacBookAir/ND*, ie /Volumes .
I tried the obvious, `open "$P"`. I also tried cd-ing to the directory and doing `open .`

ND (with the eject symbol) is visible both at the top level and at path P.

Comment: I find your description unclear. Please use more realistic and explicit examples and clarify the difference between what you want and what's actually happening. You may need to show screenshots. In any case: try dragging the thing that works the way you want from the Finder to a Terminal window to see what path gets auto-typed. Also, be aware that not every location you can open in the Finder exists in the file system or has a path. For example, Go > Computer has no analog in the file system. Neither does Go > Network.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/GnF8q The first image is what is happening, the second is what I want to happen.

Comment: You've cut off the title bar in those screenshots. What is the container/folder whose contents is showing in the second screenshot?

Comment: The location in which I mounted the drive, ~/Documents/.../...

Comment: Edit your question to show the commands you use to mount the volume and show the result of `ls -l "$P"` and/or `ls -ld "$P/$ND"`. Does it look like a symlink? Also, what's the output from `mount -v`?